# Hotkey for showing/hiding sidebar

Tags: visual-studio-2010, hotkeys

Is there a way to quickly toggl show(+focus)/collapse(+unfocus) Visual Studio 2010's sidebar (eg: solution explorer) with a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Un-Pin the sidebars (the beautifully drawn pin icon between next to the X).

Then look at the available shortcuts under "**View**".  For Example:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> - `View.SolutionExplorer`

Comment: Tried that before. But couldn't make it go away by typing the same hotkey again. Off course escape does that trick. Thanks